# how to rewrite the media path using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently my website images, css, js path is like this. It is very lengthy. I want to hide some part of URL using .htaccess look into this example.

```
http://www.mysite.com/themes/global/css/style.css
http://www.mysite.com/themes/global/js/script.js
http://www.mysite.com/themes/global/images/logo.png
....
```

This is what I want without changing the current directory structure using .htaccess

```
http://www.mysite.com/css/style.css
http://www.mysite.com/js/script.js
http://www.mysite.com/images/logo.png
....
```

How can i do this? It is good to do or bad please comment. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, first check if you're accessing a css, js, or image, then rewrite the short URI to the full URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/themes/global/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /themes/global/$1 [L]
```